# Performance issues in writing to large files?

Tags: file, logging, file-io, performance

I have been recently involved in handling the console logs for a server and I was wondering, out of curiosity, that is there a performance issue in writing to a large file as compared to small ones.

For instance is it a good idea to keep the log file size small instead of letting them grow bulky, but I was not able to argue much in favor of either approach.

There might be problems in reading or searching in the file, but right now I am more interested in knowing if writing can be affected in any way.
Looking for an expert advice.

Edit:
The way I thought it was that the OS only has to open a file handle and push the data to the file system. There is little correlation to the file size, since you have to keep on appending the data to the end of the file and whenever a block of data is full, OS will assign another block to the file. As I said earlier, there can be problems in reading and searching because of defragmentation of file blocks, but I could not find much difference while writing.

Comment: If you are using ext or other modern Unix/Linux file system, then filling you disk with (appended) log-files, is about the only use-case that will cause your file-system to fragment (If you are on Microsoft's windows, then ignore this, just about every use-case (that has concurrency or deletion) will cause your file-system to fragment). To mitigate this fragmentation, rotate and zip your log-files (use a log rotation tool for this). zipping will not only reduce file size, it will also de-fragment the file.

Comment: There's probably a more important issue: manageability.  While writing to the log file is important, how you handle storage management (log rotation, export, etc) will pretty much be the most visible part of your architecture.  Most applications cap their log files at some size or limit the data to a particular time range (day/week/etc).  This gives many smaller files that you can manage more gracefully than a single file.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As a general rule, there should be no practical difference between appending a block to a small file (or writing the first block which is appending to a zero-length file) or appending a block to a large file.

There are special cases (like trying to fault in a triple-indirect block or the initial open having to read all mapping information) which could add additional I/O's. but the steady-state should be the same.

I'd be more worried about the manageability of having huge files: slow to backup, slow to copy, slow to view, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert, but I will try to answer anyway.

Larger files may take longer to write on disk and in fact it is not a programming issue. It is file system issue. Perhaps there are file systems, which does not have such issues, but on Windows large files cannot be write down in one piece so fragmenting them will take time (for the simple reason that head will have to move to some other cylinder). Assuming that we are talking about "classic" hard drives...

If you want an advice, I would go for writing down smaller files and rotating them either daily or when they hit some size (or both actually). That is rather common approach I saw in an enterprise-grade products.

Comment: The way I thought it was that the OS only has to open a file handle and push the data to the file system. There is little correlation to the file size, since you have to keep on appending the data to the end of the file and whenever a block of data is full, OS will assign another block to the file.